# Check password matches the condition in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am creating admin user account by prompting for user input  through Ansible. This admin account

```yaml
vars_prompt:
  - name: "Username"
    prompt:  "Enter the administrator username"
    private: no

  - name: "Password"
    prompt: "Enter the administrator password.Password must contain at least 8 total printable ASCII character(s)."
    private: yes

  - name: "Confirm_Password"
    prompt: Confirm Password
    private: yes
```

I want to check if the password length is greater or equal to 8 and it contains only ASCII chars.

I tried something like this:

```yaml
- name : Password matches the splunk condition
  assert:
    that:
      - Password | length >= 8 and chars=ascii_letters
    success_msg: "Passed."
    fail_msg: "New password is too short!"
    quiet: true
  tags: password_check
```

But it isn't working.

Comment: Why restrict a password to only contain ASCII letters? It seems like a bad practice that seriously decreases security.

Comment: "This isnt working." In what way? Are you getting an error message, or incorrect results? Where are you setting the `chars` variable?

Comment: something raw `echo 123456み8| perl -ne 'if(/^[[:ascii:]]{8}$/){print "good";exit 0}else{print "bad";exit 1}'` , notice the input supplied to `echo` here.  The return value of this command may be used for assertion.

Comment: Creating admin account for UF installation has password policy :


Password must contain at least 8 total printable ASCII character(s).

This is why I was trying to limit to only ASCII chars

Answer (score 2):

Q: ***"Test if password length is greater or equal to 8 and it contains only ASCII chars."***

A: The limitation to all [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters is not practical. The regex below limits the string to 8 or more **printable** ASCII characters. See [Regex for all PRINTABLE characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247762/regex-for-all-printable-characters/31740504)

```yaml
    - assert:
        that: Password is match('^[ -~]{8,}$')
        fail_msg: "Password: {{ Password }} does not comply!"
        quiet: true
```

- Fit the [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#regular-expression-howto) to your needs.
- See other options [How to test a regex password in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990654/how-to-test-a-regex-password-in-python).