# Check if password matches condition

Tags: ansible

I am getting user input for a password in my Ansible task. This user input is passed through command to 'password variable'. I want to check if given password matches below condition:

- length greater than 8
- password should contain only printable ASCII chars

I tried something like this :

```yaml
- fail: msg="Password validation failed" 
  when: password | default('') | length <= 0 | chars = ascii_letters
```

This is not working.

If I am using fail module only for password non empty and length check, it is working.

```yaml
- fail: msg="Password validation failed" 
  when: password | default('') | length <= 0 | chars = ascii_letters
```

Comment: Use the proper module instead: [`assert`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html), with it, you can pass as much condition as you like in a list.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε

I used this way:


- name : Check if password is long enough
      assert:
        that:
          - password | length > 8 | chars = ascii_letters
        success_msg: "Passed."
        fail_msg: "Password validation failed"
        quiet: true

its not working.

Comment: `| chars = ascii_letters` this Is not a valid filter, nor in Ansible, nor in Jinja.

Comment: Also `password | length > 8` will give you a boolean, you cannot chain another filter on it, as it will test the returned boolean, not the string in `password` anymore.

Comment: Please help me how can I do ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check password matches the condition in ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72049059/check-password-matches-the-condition-in-ansible)

Answer (score 1):

To check if a string contains only ASCII character, the best would be to use a regular expression, which you can `assert` with the [`regex` test](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings).

As regex are pretty powerful, you could also bake your character limitation in it.

Here would be a task achieving this:

```yaml
- name: Assert a string of 8+ ASCII char
  assert:
    that:
      - password is string
      - password is regex('^[\x00-\x7F]{8,}$')
```

And some results based on use cases:

- errors if we do not send anything as `--extra-vars`

  ```yaml
  fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
    assertion: password is string
    evaluated_to: false
    msg: Assertion failed
  ```
- errors if we pass a too short password: `--extra-vars "password=1234567"`

  ```yaml
  fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
    assertion: password is regex('^[\x00-\x7F]{8,}$')
    evaluated_to: false
    msg: Assertion failed
  ```
- also errors in the regex if we pass a non-ASCII char: `--extra-vars "password=1234567é"`

  ```yaml
  fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
    assertion: password is regex('^[\x00-\x7F]{8,}$')
    evaluated_to: false
    msg: Assertion failed
  ```
- pass the assertion with `--extra-vars "password=12345678"`

  ```yaml
  ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
    msg: All assertions passed
  ```

Comment: You can find another example under [Check password matches the condition in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72049548/6771046).