# Go regexp for printable characters

Tags: regex, go

I have a Go server application that processes and saves a user-specified name. I really don't care what the name is; if they want it to be in hieroglyphs or emojis that's fine, as long as most clients can display it. Based on [this question for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247762/regex-for-all-printable-characters) I was hoping to use

```
^[^\p{Cc}\p{Cn}\p{Cs}]{1,50}$
```

basically 1-50 characters that are not control characters, unassigned characters, or partial UTF-16 characters. But Go [does not support Cn](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax). Basically I can't find a reasonable regexp that will match any printable unicode string but not "퟿͸", for example.

I want to use regex because the clients are not written in Go and I want to be able to precisely match the server validation. It's not clear how to match functions like `isPrint` in other languages.

Is there any way to do this other than hard-coding the unassigned unicode ranges into my application and separately checking for those?

Comment: Any reason you need to use regexp? There is [strconv/unicode.IsPrint](https://pkg.go.dev/strconv#IsPrint)

Comment: I want to use regex because the clients are not written in Go and I want to be able to write matching client-side validation. It's not clear how to match `isPrint` in other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use just these Unicode character classes:

- L (Letter)
- M (Mark)
- P (Punctuation)
- S (Symbol)

That would give you this [positive] regular expression:

```
^[\pL\pM\pN\pP\pS]+$
```

Alternatively, test for those Unicode character classes which you don't want:

- Z (Separator)
- C (Other)

Again, a positive regular expression:

```
^[^\pZ\pC]+$
```

Comment: Makes sense. Looks like CLMPSZ covers all of unicode so breaking it down this way gives equivalent behavior. Thanks!